# PHP PDO MySQL LIKE and prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Assume `$search` is a string from user input, and `$db` is a valid PDO reference.

From what I understand, the following block is preferred and should work:

```
$imageStatement = $db->prepare("SELECT
images.whatever
FROM images
WHERE images.title LIKE :titleSearch OR images.description LIKE :descriptionSearch");
$imageStatement->bindValue(':titleSearch', "%{$search}%");
$imageStatement->bindValue(':descriptionSearch', "%{$search}%");
$images = $imageStatement->fetchAll();
```

It gives back 0 results, while the following gives back the expected returns:

```
$search = $db->quote("%{$search}%");
$images = $db->query("SELECT
images.whatever
FROM images
WHERE images.title LIKE {$search} OR images.description LIKE {$search}")->fetchAll();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never executed your PDO statement.  After binding your parameters, call `execute` before retrieving your results.

```
$imageStatement->bindValue(':titleSearch', "%{$search}%");
$imageStatement->bindValue(':descriptionSearch', "%{$search}%");
$imageStatement->execute(); //ADD THIS STATEMENT
$images = $imageStatement->fetchAll();
```

PDO's `query` function does not require you to call `execute`, because it is not a parameterized query.

Comment: yikes - I'm an idiot - just forgot to execute - I'll accept as soon as I can (6 minutes).  Thanks

Comment: @BigMoMo Not a problem.  We all make those kinds of mistakes.